# error: TypeError: handlerInput.serviceClientFactory.getReminderManagementServiceClient is not a function

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to create a Reminder in Alexa to alert me in x amount of minutes but keep getting getReminderManagementServiceClient is not a function, even though i checked the Index file and updated the SDK.

```
const client = handlerInput.serviceClientFactory.getReminderManagementServiceClient();

var date = new Date();

var timestamp = date.getTime();

const reminderRequest = {
    "trigger": {
      "type" : "SCHEDULED_RELATIVE",
        "offsetInSeconds" : "30"
            },
                "alertInfo": {
                    "spokenInfo": {
                        "content": [{
                            "locale": event.request.locale,
                            //"locale": "en-US",
                            "text": `The price of ${companyName} now is ${latestPrice}`
                        }]
                    }
                },
                "pushNotification" : {
                    "status" : "ENABLED"
                }
       }
      const reminderResponse = await client.createReminder(reminderRequest);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(reminderResponse));
```

`error: TypeError: handlerInput.serviceClientFactory.getReminderManagementServiceClient is not a function`

Answer (score 1):

Your answer helped me.  I needed to update the sdk.  Here are a few things that I also had to do to get it working.  Maybe this can help you

Are you using `ask-sdk-core`?

```
const Alexa = require('ask-sdk-core');
```

Do you have the `.withApiClient(new Alexa.DefaultApiClient())`?  https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/issues/356

```
const skillBuilder = Alexa.SkillBuilders.custom();
exports.handler = skillBuilder
    .addRequestHandlers(...)
    .withApiClient(new Alexa.DefaultApiClient())
    .withSkillId(...)
    .lambda();
```

Good luck!